Laravel Storage Didn't Save Any Pictures Inside storage\app\public

So I'm trying to make a form to upload an image in MySQL under the endpoint /picture/create, and this is what my migration looks like:
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pictures', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name'); // there is file name column
            $table->string('path'); // and there is the path
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('pictures');
    }
};

and then these are the fillables in my Picture.php model:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Picture extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable =  [
        'name',
        'path'
    ];
}

this is what PictureController.php looks like:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\Models\Picture;

class PictureController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function create() {
        return view('create_picture');
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $name = $request->name;
        
        $path = time() . '_' . $request->name . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
        Storage::disk('local')->put('public/', $path, file_get_contents($file) );
     
        Picture::create([
            'name' => $name,
            'path' => $path
        ]);

        return Redirect::route('picture.create');
    }
}

this is what my blade views under the name create_picture.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Create Picture</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ route('picture.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"> <br>
        <input type="file" name="file"> <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

And inside the router I make the endpoint to the blade view using the PictureController:
use App\Http\Controllers\PictureController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// file storage
Route::get('/picture/create', [PictureController::class, 'create'])->name('picture.create');
Route::post('/picture/create', [PictureController::class, 'store'])->name('picture.store');

What is weird is that everytime I upload image in local, it shows up the data entry inside pictures table in phpMyAdmin, but it did not shows any pictures inside the storage\app\public directory.
p.s. I already migrate:fresh the database and linking the storage php artisan storage:link

file_get_contents($file) won't work because $file isn't the file path, it is a Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile object.
You can use file_get_contents($file->path()), or you can use UploadFile's built-in storeAs() method, like this (docs):
$file->storeAs('public', $path, 'local');

@MosheKatz It works on me, I appreciate it. It's difficult to find PHPers around this forum.

You can use the store method from the $request itself. Follow below snippet:
$image_path = $request->file('file')->store('uploads', 'public');

